# Systemd service should be running, but remains in active exited

Tags: systemd

The service below, which should be in active running state, is in active exited state. Have tried restarting the service, but it did not work.

Output of `sudo systemctl status ecm-document-app`:

```
ecm-document-app.service - "ecm-document-app service"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ecm-document-app.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-31 08:08:48 EDT; 5h 10min ago
 Main PID: 12741 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ecm-document-app.service

Aug 31 08:08:48 d01decmwf01.independenthealth.com systemd[1]: Starting "ecm-...
Aug 31 08:08:48 d01decmwf01.independenthealth.com app_util.sh[12727]:     Sat Au...
Aug 31 08:08:48 d01decmwf01.independenthealth.com app_util.sh[12727]: Sat Au...
Aug 31 08:08:48 d01decmwf01.independenthealth.com systemd[1]: Started "ecm-d...
Aug 31 08:08:48 d01decmwf01.independenthealth.com systemd[1]: ecm-document-a...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Add the output of `journalctl-xe` after the service fails to start to your question. Does the service have a log file? If so, add its contents to your question.

Comment: systemd[1]: Stopping "ecm-document-app service"...
app_util.sh[8195]: Sat Aug 31 14:21:53 EDT 2019 List of PIDs of ecm-document-app Application:
app_util.sh[8195]: Sat Aug 31 14:21:53 EDT 2019 ecm-document-app is not running ...
systemd[1]: Stopped "ecm-document-app service".
systemd[1]: Unit ecm-document-app.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: ecm-document-app.service failed.

Comment: systemd[1]: Starting "ecm-document-app service"...
app_util.sh[8214]: Sat Aug 31 14:21:53 EDT 2019 Starting application ecm-document-app.....
app_util.sh[8214]: Sat Aug 31 14:21:53 EDT 2019 Configuration server path is https://esbconfig.development.independenthealth.com:9090/api .
app_util.sh[8214]: Sat Aug 31 14:21:53 EDT 2019 ecm-document-app started.
systemd[1]: Started "ecm-document-app service".
systemd[1]: ecm-document-app.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: Hi Nasir,kindly have a look on the log file above

Comment: Add the output to your question so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: Also add the output of `tail -n 20 /var/log/messages` after attempting to start the service to your question.

Comment: I am not able to add output to the question

Comment: plz go to
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/538597/the-service-below-which-should-be-in-active-running-state-is-in-active-exited

Comment: why don't you try asking an actual question ... perhaps then you will receive an answer